# Is it enough to just enlarge font sizes for mobile without making the whole layout responsive?

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, responsive-design

I have a legacy e-commerce site heavily styled from the desktop era and have been making good money. They are based on a very sophisticated e-commerce software and it costs an arm and a leg to make the whole site responsive per present standards.

According to my GA analytics, I'm potentially letting go of thousands of dollars per month in sales with the majority of my site's traffic being mobile yet converting at less than half of conversion rate of the desktop traffic.

I will make the site responsive when I have more time but for now what's the single most important and easiest thing I can do to make the site more usable on mobile devices?

Considering iPhone Safari is pretty good at rendering desktop sites with regards to usability, I think responsive layout isn't the priority here.

My idea is to enlarging the font sizes of all the texts and sizes of all buttons, by, say 50%, for all mobile devices.

Would this work and make the mobile experience better if not perfect? What could be the potential problem for this very biased and partial approach?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the site on a mobile device? There may be something unique to your particular page layout that makes a button difficult to select (or locate), or navigation hard to use.  There's no "magic bullet" or "one simple trick" and there's no substitute for testing.

Answer (score 2):

The way that most desktop sites appear on mobile means that making the text size larger isn't going to be quite as helpful as you might like and may break the layout - potentially making the experience even worse.

From an ecommerce point of view, my suggestion would be to have another look at your Google Analytics and see where in the funnel most of your drop off is. Is it on a product page, or cart page, or checkout?

Depending on the answer to this, you might be able to get away with just making those few pages responsive in the meantime. If people are getting to the checkout and then dropping off, making the checkout responsive might be a better action than trying to fix a little bit of the entire site.

You obviously know that the entire site should be responsive, and it's just a matter of time and effort, so a good stop gap might be to just pick those pages with the highest drop off rates and style them to be a little better. It's not going to be a great experience for the user, but if it's only for a few months, it's going to be better than nothing.